# Can you have multiple graphs per XY axis?

Tags: javascript, nvd3.js

I'm using nvd3.js and I'm trying to add multiple charts to one graph. I know you can do this in AmCharts, but I couldn't figure out if you could with nvd3.js. I did successfully graph 2 graphs in the same div, but they're both graphed on their own respective axes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking if it's possible to add multiple data series to the same graph... the answer is yes, as it's shown in the examples page of NVD3...

Here an example of a lineChart with two lines:

http://nvd3.org/ghpages/line.html

If this is not what you are looking for, please add more info!